# Undefined Object Jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, eventbrite

I'm trying to figure out the [Eventbrite](https://www.eventbrite.com/developer/v3/) api and I've gotten something to work, but not what I want.

Below is my code. The first script works. The second one does not and yields this error: ***102TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.name.text')***

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/17920884849/?token=NR4COIXFSOYKGDDG6MSP",
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {}
  }

  $.ajax(settings).done(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    var content = "<h2>" + data.name.text + "</h2>" + data.description.html;
    jQuery("#eventbrite").append(content);
  });
</script>
<div id="eventbrite"></div>

<h1>Another test</h1>

<script>
  var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/organizers/12748782127/events/?token=ZMDFKJWCHAMX5WFVPBAJ",
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {}
  }

  jQuery.ajax(settings).done(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    var content = "<h2>" + data.name.text + "</h2>" + data.description.html;
    jQuery("#eventbrite2").append(content);
  });
</script>
<div id="eventbrite2"></div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for down voting this, whoever did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the JSON that's returned.

The first call looks like this, so `data.name` works fine:

```
   {
    "name": {
        "text": "An Aggressive Approach to Concise Writing, with Joe Welinske", 
        "html": "An Aggressive Approach to Concise Writing, with Joe Welinske"
    },
```

The second call looks like this, so you'll need `data.events[0].name.text`:

```
{
"pagination": {
    "object_count": 1, 
    "page_number": 1, 
    "page_size": 50, 
    "page_count": 1
}, 
"events": [
    {
        "name": {
            "text": "Test Event 1", 
            "html": "Test Event 1"
```

Comment: data.events[0]['name']['text]

Comment: Ugh, I'm an idiot. So should this be my code? Still fails. `<script>
  var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/organizers/12748782127/events/?token=ZMDFKJWCHAMX5WFVPBAJ",
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {}
  }

  $.ajax(settings).done(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    var content = "<h2>" + data.events.name.text + "</h2>" + data.events.description.html;
    jQuery("#eventbrite2").append(content);
  });
</script>
<div id="eventbrite2"></div>`

Comment: Are you getting the same error or something different?  The `events[0]` part is important.  Fix that.

Comment: Ok, what I added on that line is here:     var content = "<h2>" + data.events[0].name.text + "</h2>" + data.events[0].description.html;

Comment: Ok so that returned one result. There are two. Is that an easy fix. My apologies, I'm just trying to correct this and am usually a strict HTML/CSS guy.

Comment: Apologies not needed.  Accepting my answer would be nice though. :)